# Can't find three.js after loading through Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, meteor, three.js

Been working on a system to load document-specific scripts asynchronously into a Meteor template after it's been rendered:

```
Template.postPage.onRendered(function(){

    var post = Template.currentData();

    if(post.libs) post.libs.forEach(function(e){
        console.log(e);
        $.getScript(e, function(data, text, code){
            console.log(text);
        }).done(threejs);

        function threejs(){
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        };

    });
});
```

This pattern works with Chartist, Chart.js, and d3 but doesn't seem to be working with [three.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.min.js)—all of the other libraries are available globally, but I can't seem to find the `THREE` object constructed by three.js anywhere.

Am I missing something obvious, or do I just need to wrap the contents of three.js in an anonymous function to initialise? If so, could someone provide an example/documents on how best to do so?

**Update:** I'm stumped. By switching to a CDN, `THREE` loads perfectly well. For the sake of self-sufficiency I'd like to host from my own server—if anyone can recommend any additional tests, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: by including three.js, the object THREE should be available. Make sure that three.js loaded before trying to access it.

Comment: @2pha check the `.done()` method I just added to the end of `$.getScript()`—even when it explicitly waits for the script to be loaded, it's not able to find `THREE`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out for my own project - the way to make this work is to edit the `three.min.js` source file.

Removing/commenting `'use strict';` at the start of `three.min.js` lets it load correctly.

This seems to be related to the following feature/issue of meteor: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1380

The CDN was likely un-minified and didn't contain `'use strict;'`. To be safe, `'use strict;'` should probably be placed after the global `THREE` namespace has been declared.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Had to put this project down for a while, but I'll have to give this a shot. Thanks!