# How can I load three.js for specific templates

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, three.js

I know of two main approaches for loading external libraries into meteor, (as discussed in e.g. http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/use-meteor-iron-router-waiton-to-load-external-javascript).

In addition there are meteor packages to load `three.js` **globally**.

Does anyone know how to use a template - level approach to get `THREE` working? I don't want `three.js` to load on all of the routes, but my attempt so far using ~

```
Template.threeview.onRendered(function(){

    Session.setDefault('threejs', false);
    // is library already loaded?
    if (Session.get('threejs') === false) {
        console.log('Requesting threejs...')
        $.getScript('/js/three.min.js', function() {
            Session.set('threejs', true);
            // the THREE object should now be accessible here
            // as well as in the window environment...?
            console.log(window.THREE);
            console.log(THREE);
        });
    };
});
```

doesn't work - I get

```
undefined 
Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
```

in the js console window.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Found this similar question [Can't find three.js after loading through Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292027/cant-find-three-js-after-loading-through-ajax) which suffers the same problem - I can confirm that loading from CDN works. Does any one have a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out - the way to make this work is to edit the `three.min.js` source file. 
Removing/commenting `'use strict';` at the start of `three.min.js` lets it load correctly.

This seems to be related to the following feature/issue of meteor: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1380

The CDN was un-minified and didn't contain `'use strict;'`. To be safe, `'use strict;'` should probably be placed after the global `THREE` namespace has been declared.